# Why doesn't this code remove all odd integers from the ArrayList?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have an ArrayList of 10 positive nonzero integers.

```
0: 1103
1: 711
2: 199
3: 1527
4: 1745
5: 1530
6: 984
7: 798
8: 927
9: 1986
```

When I run this

```
for(int i = 0; i < l1.length; i++){
        int temp = l1.retrieveAt(i);
        int temp2 = temp % 2;
        if(temp2 == 1){
            l1.removeAt(i);
        }
    }
```

The list changes to

```
0: 711
1: 1527
2: 1530
3: 984
4: 798
5: 1986
```

l1 is an object of [UnorderedArrayList](https://pastebin.com/tfSZMH6A) which extends [ArrayListClass](https://pastebin.com/aDNPpxY5) which implements [ArrayListADT](https://pastebin.com/9ZaB26gj) (click for pastebin)

`retrieveAt(index)` and `removeAt(index)` are methods of ArrayListClass.

Comment: You've said that it's an `ArrayList`, then you say it's some `UnorderedArrayList` you've made.  Which is it?  Please include all relevant code in the post itself, instead of linking to it.

Comment: why don't you shorten your code inside the for loop to if(l1.retrieveAt(i) % 2 == 1) ?

Comment: If element `n` is even, you don't remove it, and the *next* element to examine is `n + 1`. But if it's odd, and you remove it from the list, which element takes its place at index `n`?

Comment: alternative to answers: do not increment `i` if the number was removed...

Answer (score 5):

Removing values at an index while iterating using that index can cause elements to be skipped. For example, if we remove the element at index `0`, the list becomes:

```
0: 711
1: 199      <--- next element to check
2: 1527
3: 1745
4: 1530
5: 984
6: 798
7: 927
8: 1986
```

The index is now incremented to `1` for the next iteration of the loop, so the new first element (`711`, which is the element at the *new* position `0`) is skipped. This pattern repeats for the rest of the values.

An option is to use the [Iterator Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterator_pattern), as supposed by all Java `Collection` classes (such as `ArrayList`). Using this style, you can rewrite your loop as follows:

```
for (Iterator<Integer> it = l1.iterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {
    int temp = it.next();
    int temp2 = temp % 2;
    if (temp2 == 1) {
        it.remove();
    }
}
```

---

As stated in **phatfingers**'s answer, iterating from the highest value first would remove this problem. The loop would be the same, but it would start at the last index (`l1.length - 1`) and continue until it reaches `0`. Thus, the indices would be `[9, 8, ..., 0]` rather than the original `[0, 1, ..., 9]`. The code for this solution would be:

```
for (int i = l1.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    int temp = l1.retrieveAt(i);
    int temp2 = temp % 2;
    if(temp2 == 1){
        l1.removeAt(i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[I'm amending my answer a bit.]

Once you remove an item from the list, all the items below it shift up, so you end up skipping the next item at each deletion because it shifted into the index you just processed.  If you work your way from the bottom up, you won't run into this problem.

Here's some example code.  (As a reminder for others, this is based on the OP's proprietary class, and not on a standard ArrayList):

```
for (int i=l1.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
    if ((l1.retrieveAt(i)&1) == l) 11.removeAt(i);
}
```

Comment: For clarification: Wouldn't the condition for the for loop need to be `i >= 0` so that element `0` is included?

Comment: Yes.  Good catch!

Answer (score 0):

When you call `l1.removeAt(i)`, this changes the indices of the remaining elements.

The value of 711 will not be checked because you only check position 0 once, and remove the odd element at position 0. 711 moves to position 0, and you continue checking from position 1.